# Can I force a passed object to implement one or more interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, delegates, protocols

I am trying to write a class that relies on an object being passed to its constructor when initiated. This object should be of a certain abstract base class and has to implement an interface defined within the to be initiated class. Yet I do not know if this is possible in Java. The code should look something like this:

```
// The Base class implementing all basic functionality
abstract class A {
    public void letBaseDoSomething() {
        System.out.println("A does something...");
    }
}

// Child class extending A
public class B extends A implements Z_requirements {
    public void letMoreDoSomething() {
        System.out.println("B does something...");
    }
    public Boolean canDoStuff() { /* functionality */}
}

// Now this is the class I want to initiate:
public class Z {
    public interface Z_requirements {
        Boolean canDoStuff();
    }

    public Z(<A implements Z_requirements> base) {
        // PROBLEM
        // This "base" class needs to both extend from the
        // Base class AND implement the Z_requirements interface
        // but apart from defining it in the doc, how do I enforce
        // this in code? This way I can call both:
        base.letBaseDoSomething();
        // and
        base.canDoStuff();
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly, in Objective-C one could specify delegate object that implements several "protocols" which are basically interfaces.

**Update:**

Actually, I might have approved a bit too quickly... Following the suggestion below, how would I now assign `T base` to a delegate object, private to `Z`? E.g.:

```
public class Z<T extends A & Z.Z_requirements> {
    public static interface Z_requirements {/* definition */}
    private T delegate;
    public Z(T base) {
        delegate=base;
    }
}
```

If I use this code, I always get a "type safety" warning:

```
Z z = new Z(class_B_implementing_Z_requirements);
```

...and if I include `<T>` in the constructor I get a "type undefined" error:

```
Z<T> z = new Z<T>(class_B_implementing_Z_requirements);
```

**Update**

I figured it out since I misunderstood types:

```
Z<B> z = new Z<B>(class_B_implementing_Z_requirements);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Declare a generic method with a [type parameter that is bounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) by multiple types:

```
public static <T extends A & Z_requirements> void doIt(T base) {
    base.letBaseDoSomething();
    base.canDoStuff();
}
```

Or - if you want to do it in the constructor - you must constrain your class `Z` in the same way:

```
public class Z<T extends A & Z.Z_requirements> {
    public static interface Z_requirements {
        Boolean canDoStuff();
    }

    public Z(T base) {
        base.letBaseDoSomething();
        base.canDoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I might have approved a bit too quickly... How would I now assign `T base` to a delegate object, private to `Z`? Example added to question...

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface W { public Boolean canDoStuff() { /* so do it */ } }

public ZZTop extends B implements W
{
  // ...
}

public Z
{
  public Z(ZZtop zztop) {}
}
```

ZZTop will inherit from B and must implement canDoStuff from W.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP wanted to know how to constrain a method parameter to specific types. You explained how to create a class that fulfills this constraint. I would downvote, but mentioning `ZZTop` is worth an upvote. Equal. :-)

Comment: That was what I though of initially. But doing it this way, causes the class I pass into `Z` would only be a super-class of `ZZTop` or a different child-class of `W` and is not compatible with `Z`'s constructor.